# IStringLocalizer<T> doesn't work in Asp.Net core Blazor Server

Tags: localization, blazor, resourcemanager

I have set it up for localization as follows:

Set the neutralLanguage for the project,

```xml
// .csproj
<NeutralLanguage>ko-KR</NeutralLanguage>
```

Registered localization services into the service container,

```cs
// program.cs
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options =>
        {
            options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
        }) ;

...

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
     .AddSupportedCultures(new[] { "ko-KR", "en-US" })
     .AddSupportedUICultures(new[] { "ko-KR", "en-US"}));

...
```

Created a .resx file in ~\Resource directory with VS 2022, which created .Designer.cs in the directory as per to my configuration

```
//~\Resources
UIStrings.resx
UIStrings.Designer.cs
```

Added a string resource into UIStrings.resx, for example:

```
Name : "이름"
```

FYI, "이름" is Korean for English "name".

and, I am seeing the below result:

```
// .razor
...
@inject IStringLocalizer<UIStrings> Localizer

...

@UIStrings.Name                              // prints "이름"
@UIStrings.ResourceManager.GetString("Name") // prints "이름"
@Localizer["Name"]                            // prints "Name" <= not good
```

I don't know why IStringLocalizer doesn't work.

Comment: `.GetString("Name")`  Gets the resource with the current UI culture.  `.GetString("Name", CultureInfo)` gets the culture desired.

Comment: @BrianParker yes, it is working fine. I want IStringLocalizer to work fine, too.

Comment: Blazor Server or WASM?

Comment: @BrianParker it's Server

Comment: So the default CI is the servers... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some code and found how `IStringLocalizer<T>` behaves and how it differs from the behavior of `ResourceManager`.

The failure of my question was from different file-location behavior of `IStringLocalizer`.

All relevant comments are added between code shown here:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using ResourceManagementExam.Controls;
using ResourceManagementExam.Pages;
using ResourceManagementExam.Resources; // <== to identify Resource1 class
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;

namespace ResourceManagementExam;
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        var app = builder.Build();

        // ResourceManager
        // requires the root name of the argument to be identical to that of .resx by default.         
        var rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resource1)); 

        Console.WriteLine($"UI Culture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture}");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello : " + rm.GetString("Hello"));
        Console.WriteLine();


        // IStringLocalizer<T>
        // options.ResourcesPath = "Resources", which is the relative root path.
        var programLocalizer = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>>();
        Prints(programLocalizer);

        var indexPageLocalizer = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer<IndexPage>>();

        Prints(indexPageLocalizer);

        var searchBarLocalizer = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer<SearchBar>>();

        Prints(searchBarLocalizer);
    }

    private static void Prints(IStringLocalizer localizer)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ko-KR");
        Console.WriteLine($"UI Culture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture}");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello : " + localizer["Hello"]);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Console.WriteLine($"UI Culture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture}");
        Console.WriteLine("Hello : " + localizer["Hello"]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The project folder structure is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<UIStrings> Localizer;
<p>@Localizer[UIStrings.Name]</p>
```

Comment: IStringLocalizer returns key value when it can't find the key from the resource. So, the code just returns the result of calling UIStrings.Name

Comment: Try to delete your resource file and recreate it with this name `ResourceUIStrings` and use the way up. Be sure when you create resource file that `Access Modifier` is public.

Comment: I am not so crazy. they are all public.

Comment: `UIStrings.Name` is looking up the _localized value_ of the string. In the code here, that value is then passed as the _key_, which isn't correct. Perhaps you need a `nameof(UIStrings.Name)` to get the correct key.